# Where is a resource for theming drupal 7 views?

Tags: theming

I needed to theme a view in drupal 7 for example the slider in this site:
http://fourkitchens.com/

What file must i create to costumize a view slider and the relative button?
In drupal 6 there were theme information and i could create a new "view-example.tpl.php" and costumize it very well but in drupal 7 ?
Thank you you are great,Drupal Answers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views for Drupal 7 also provide theme information. See the advance section or follow the URL (in my case)
`example.com/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/[my_view]/[type]/analyze-theme`

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [skinr project](http://drupal.org/project/skinr). It'll allow you to skin views. I would be very careful though as the D7 version of skinr is still very experimental as stated on the release notes page.

Drupalcon 2010 session on skinr: http://www.archive.org/details/ThemingWithSkinr